# Losing float precision in for loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, floating-point

I have a list of floats taken from an sqlite3 db. From it I want to find the first two numbers greater than a number, say 18 in this case, and enumerate their position in the db.

The db list:

```
pr = [(20.49999999999983,), (16.29999999999967,), (13.799999999999102,), (18.600000000000705,), (9.600000000000364,), (11.599999999999966,), (25.30000000000001,)...]
```

Hence I try the following:

```
fnd =([i[0] for i in pr if i[0] > 18])
>>> [20.49999999999983, 18.600000000000705, 25.30000000000001]

for j in fnd:
    print ([i for i,k in enumerate(pr) if k == j])
```

For which I get 3 empty lists. I am assuming my problem comes from the fact that the float is being rounded when I use the for loop.

```
for j in fnd:
    print j

>>>20.5, 18.6, 25.3
```

Can anyone offer a workaround?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595425/what-is-the-best-way-to-compare-floats-for-almost-equality-in-python

Comment: You are also comparing a tuple to a float. Change your comprehenction to `[i for i,k in enumerate(pr) if k[0] == j]`

Comment: @mehtunguh  Thats better, thanks.

Comment: The so-called "duplicate" has nothing to do with this question.

Answer (score 0):

`k` takes the values of the elements of `pr`, which are *1-tuples* containing numbers.

`j` takes the values of the elements of `fnd`, which you constructed as the list of *numbers* greater than 18.

When you compare `k` to `j`, you compare a tuple with a number. They are never equal.